# Pairwise alignment of multi-FASTA file sequences

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta, pairwise

I have multi-FASTA file containing more than 10 000 fasta sequences resulted from Next Generation Sequencing and I want to do pairwise alignment of each sequence to each sequence inside the file and store all the results in the same new file in order to perform clustering analysis after. Example of FASTA sequence and my code for performing pairwise sequence alignment with python is written below.

#### FASTA sequence

```
>m180921_230442_42149_c101464342550000001823297908121882_s1_X0/538/ccs
AGAAGCCACTCATCCATCCAGGCAGGAAGACTCTTAGGATCCTGACTTTCTCCTGGTCCCCACATCCCCT
AAACCGAGGAAGGGGTCCAGCAGGGTCCGAGTCCCTGAAGCAAGGATTCTCCGTGGTCGTGTCCCCACAG
```

Please disregard the first line as it contains description summary of the sequence.

#### My code

```py
    from Bio import pairwise2
    from Bio.pairwise2 import format_alignment

    X = "ACGGGT"
    Y = "ACG"

    #match score = 2, mismatch score = -1, gap opening = -5, gap extension = -2
    alignments = pairwise2.align.globalms(X, Y, 2, -1, -5, -2)

    for a in alignments:
        print(format_alignment(*a))
```

#### The problem

I am wondering how can I modify it to loop over whole multi-FASTA file rather than just a code sequence.
Also: How do I efficiently store the results as needed.

Comment: Hi Aurora, welcome to SO! May you please edit your code and explain for the wider audience briefly what [FASTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA). Also, I am not quite sure how your problem and your code relate: I do not see any procedure for storing yet in your code.

Comment: @B--rian Thanks for suggestions, I edited post, but for the code I have no idea how to proceede next.

Comment: Also: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42334644/ answer your question?

Comment: You can read your FASTA file with `SeqIO.parse()` and generate the combinations via one of the itertools modules. However, I'm not sure the Biopython pairwise aligner is best suited to clustering- why not use `Bio.Clustuer`? Or an external clustering tool like mmseqs or cd-hit?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I wanted to use Biopython just for pairwise alignment and then proceede to clustering with some other moduels so that in the end I can generate consensus sequence. Thanks for suggestions

Comment: If this is just a learning exercise then go ahead, but tools like mmseqs and cd-hit do generate a consensus/representative sequence

Comment: @Chris_Rands I will try with cd-hit then. But I have thousands of reads from 12 different sites stored in one FASTA file, is that a problem?

Comment: assemble the reads first

Answer (score 2):

**First step: generate the pairs to be aligned**

You probably want to align sequences only one time against each other, e.g. if you have sequences 1, 2 and 3, you only want to align 1vs2, 1vs3 and 2vs3 (i.e. all combinations), discarding 2vs1 and 3vs2 and self-alignments. This will save you some running time:

```
from itertools import combinations
from Bio import SeqIO

combinations(SeqIO.parse(infile, "fasta"), 2)
```

**Step 2: align the pairs generated**

The function `pairwise2.align.globalms` returns a tuple of `(seqA, seqB, score, begin, end)`. We need to create `SeqRecord` objects from this tuples to be able to save it to files, adding the Scores as a `description` and preserving `name` and `id`:

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord

def align(pair):
    """Yield two Seqs aligned."""
    al = pairwise2.align.globalms(pair[0].seq, pair[1].seq, 2, -1, -5, -2)[0]

    yield SeqRecord(Seq(al[0]), id=pair[0].id, name=pair[0].name,
                    description=f"Score={al[2]}")
    yield SeqRecord(Seq(al[1]), id=pair[1].id, name=pair[1].name,
                    description=f"Score={al[2]}")
```

**Step 3: sewing it all together**

You can see the above functions are generators. Biopython writer deals with generated sequences cleanly, so you can just ask for pairs generated in the first function, send it to the `align` and write the yielded `SeqRecords` to an open handle:

```
input = "your_fasta.fas"

with open("output.fas", "w") as output:
    for pair in combinations(SeqIO.parse(infile, "fasta"), 2):
        SeqIO.write(align(pair), output, "fasta")
```